# JTA Transaction Rollback exception?

Tags: transactions, jta

I am using JTA Atomikos transaction with multiple datasource configuration in tomcat server.
Sometimes am getting the following exception:

> JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout);
>   nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: The
>   transaction was set to rollback only

What would be the cause for this exception ?

Comment: isn't there more information inside the stack trace ("caused by") ? Or perhaps previous errors/stack traces leading up to this point?

Answer (score 1):

Many times it could be caused by a DNS problem. Try to disable reverse-DNS-lookup in tomcat and your database (mysql for example comes preconfigured with reverse dns lookup and that causes lot of random errors). DNS uses the UDP protocol so it can randomly fail if the network is congested.

It could also be caused by a "big-slow-query".

There are many other types of problems that can cause a timeout. You probably need to pass a network scanner (tcpdump, wireshark, ...) to know the exact cause.